# Spark scala copying dataframe column to new dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an empty dataframe with schema already created.
I'm trying to add the columns to this dataframe from a new dataframe to the existing columns in a for loop.

k schema - |ID|DATE|REPORTID|SUBMITTEDDATE|

```
for(data <- 0 to range-1){
  val c = df2.select(substring(col("value"), str(data)._2, str(data)._3).alias(str(data)._1)).toDF()
  //c.show()
  k = c.withColumn(str(data)._1, c(str(data)._1))
}
k.show()
```

But the k dataframe has just one column, but it should have all the 4 columns populated with values.
I think the last line in for loop is replacing exisitng columns in the dataframe.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you adding columns to empty dataframe? Why can't you replace the entire dataframe with the current one?

Comment: the actual df2 dataframe has a single column. I have to select some substrings from the df2 dataframe and then add them to the k dataframe based on he schema.
So I created a val and then added the column to it and then replacing the exisiting column in k

Comment: Can you add example for it? We could not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VarunChelakara As per the example the df **k** will have only 1 column because you are selecting only one column into df **c** [i.e., the df2.select() clause has only one substring column selected] which then you are assigning to **k**. Also the line "c.withColumn(str(data)._1, c(str(data)._1))" is confusing/redundant. Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: @Bhuvan the df2 is a dataframe that has the data in a single column. I'm trying to divide that into multiple columns and store that in a dataframe. So, the schema for the new columns in provided in tuples. So I read the tuples and created an empty dataframe k. Now I'm iterating over the df2 to read the columns based on the substring positions and store them in k since it already has the schema.
But the .withcolumn is supposed to add new columns. So is there any other way of reading the columns and adding them to k other than using join?

Comment: Ah. That makes better sense. You probably can achieve this by doing a union of **c** on **k**. In your code you're essentially replacing the value of k every time in the loop. What you need to do is append to the the **k** df. Try ``k = k.crossJoin(c.withColumn(str(data)._1, c(str(data)._1)))``

Comment: @Bhuvan I got it working by adding a seq id to the old df and to the new df and then performing a join on the seq id

k = k.withColumn("rowid", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
var c  = df2.select(substring(col("value"), str(data)._2, str(data)._3).alias(str(data)._1)).toDF()
     c = c.withColumn("rowid", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
     k = k.join(c, Seq("rowid"))

Answer (score 3):

Add your logic and conditions and create new dataframe

```
val dataframe2 =  dataframe1.select("A","B",C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying few columns of a dataframe to another one is not possible in spark. 
Although there are few alternatives to attain the same

```
1. You need to join both the dataframe based on some join condition. 
2. Convert bot the data frame to json and do RDD Union

  val rdd = df1.toJSON.union(df2.toJSON) 
  val dfFinal = spark.read.json(rdd)
```

Comment: I have a dataframe k with 2 columns and when I run the below code, it is replacing all the existing columns in the dataframe
var c  = df2.select(substring(col("value"), str(data)._2, str(data)._3).alias(str(data)._1)).toDF()
   k = c.withColumn(str(data)._1, c(str(data)._1))

Comment: You can't iterate over data and add data to a dataframe. It not possible in spark.